# How to catch optional argument in laravel 5.2 route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want create a general route to catch the optional lang argument in my laravel 5.2 routes.

Currently I do it with this route

```
//language switcher
Route::get('lang/{lang}/{suffix}', function($lang, $suffix) {
  Session::set('applocale', $lang);
  return Redirect($suffix);
});
```

So, if you preceed your url with an optional "/lang/[lang-code]" router will change applocale and redirect to the resource.

However I would like to make in a cleaner way with regular expressions, someting like:

```
//language switcher
Route::get('(es|ca|en)/{suffix}', function($lang, $suffix) {
  Session::set('applocale', $lang);
  return Redirect($suffix);
});
```

But don't know how..

Answer (score 0):

As always say: RTM!

**Solution:**

```
// generic language switcher
// catch any route preceded with "es" ,"ca" or "en", set the applocale and 
// redirect to suffix route
Route::get('{lang}/{suffix}', function($lang, $suffix) {
  Session::set('applocale', $lang);
  return Redirect($suffix);
})
->where(['lang' => '(es|ca|en)', 'suffix' => '(.*)']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints